# Cannot find stackview in accessibility indicator in XCUITest

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I'm writing UI test cases for my view controller.it has three views

1.A header view ->Stackview -> 4 buttons

2.table View

3.footer view - > 5 buttons

All views are accessible except stackview and its child buttons

Can anyone guide me how do i get reference of stackview and its child elements?

Answer (score 13):

Set the header view and stack view to be inaccessible and the child elements to be accessible. You can do this using the UIAccessibility API, setting `isAccessibilityElement` to false for the containers. On the views you want to interact with, set `isAccessibilityElement` to true and also set `accessibilityIdentifier` on each view.

If a container view is accessible, its child views are often obscured to avoid confusion about what the user is trying to interact with.